# How do I destroy the gate in Caudecus's Manor - Explorable Mode?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Today, I recently took on Caudecus's Manor on Explorable mode. As our path, we chose to search for the hidden seraphs. After various pillow-proof traps, we came upon one of the final "events" to the dungeon.

This event required us to move five kegs to a gate, in order to break it down. However, an infinite amount of bandits are constantly stopping any player that picks up a keg. Even after placing the keg in the designated area, it is soon stolen back by the bandits.

We tried several tactics to counter these bandits:

1) Have one player take a keg and run, attracting the attention of the bandits.

- Bandits quickly switched targets to players that picked up kegs despite distance

2) Have each player bring a keg to the gate and drop at same time

- Bandits either killed a player, or were able to steal a keg before it registered

3) Place a keg in an inaccessible place

- Several bandits teleported to pick up the keg, but did not seem to affect the maximum spawns.

4) Designate players as bandit killers and others as keg runners

- Any Bandit Archer that was able to take hold of a keg was a keg lost, due to the ridiculous hp of these mobs.

What is the most efficient, and least aggravating way, of getting through this gate?

Update: Tried this a few more times, and still found it nearly impossible. I felt as if the difficult level was a bit high, so I searched around. Found a ledge that allows you to skip the wall, but it seems this is not intentional and will hopefully be fixed soon.

Answer (score 2):

The best way I found was to have 2-3 people constantly running from the barrels to the door, dropping them and the other 2 killing the adds. The adds will prioritise picking up barrels on the ground, then attack players with barrels. So if you have enough on the ground they don't damage anyone and the players not running the barrels can just kill them.

Once we figured it out it was quite easy.